# What is this eth0.bak?

Tags: linux-networking

Why do I have 2 of the same devices but different nicknames?  Do I need to delete one?  What is with this eth0.bak?  Thanks for any advice. =)

[image]

BTW, this is from RHEL virtual machine in case that helps any.

From the request below, here are some more details of my networking setup.  I don't see any other indication of a eth0.bak here.  Is it safe to just follow dmourati's instructions to bring down this eth0.back?  Thanks again.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the outputs from the following:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0*
```

Probably the person modifying that ifcfg-eth0 script didn't release that copying it to ifcfg-eth0.bak would add another config to the interface.

I'd bet you want to do:

```
$ sudo ifcfg eth0.bak down
$ sudo rm /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.bak
```

Don't do that until you post the ifconfig and cat outputs above so we can confirm there isn't something else going on.

Comment: I've posted the commands as shown above.  What do you think?  Thanks for helping.  =)

Comment: It appears that the machine or virtual machine went from being statically addressed (the .bak file: 192.168.51.25) to DHCP (ifcfg-eth0 file: 192.168.1.171).  It also appears the MAC address has changed.  As long as you are okay with the DHCP address and can access the machine, go ahead and delete ifcfg-eth0.bak.  You can skip the ifcfg eth0.bak step as it doesn't appear to be running.  I'd reboot the system and try logging in via SSH to 192.168.1.171.

Answer (score 5):

Someone made a ifcfg-eth0.bak file in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
```

Its probably a backup file

Answer (score 1):

That's a backup file.
It happens when you, for example, change the network card (hence, it's MAC ADDRESS).

Red Hat based distros happen to create a .bak file when that happens.

It's safe to delete.